# Is there a better way to write this steering angle in Unity to make it feel more natural?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm using unity's wheel colliders to create a car in a game that's meant to feel more realistic or Forza esc.

Currently I'm simply coding it like this:

```
horizontal = horizontalInput * 40;

wheelColliders[0].steerAngle = horizontal;

wheelColliders[1].steerAngle = horizontal;
```

using this it feels unnatural and sharp while driving, also the turning angle feels lackluster.

Any help on how I could improve would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a PID controller. They are used in real cars for steering and breaking assists.

```csharp
[Serializable]
public class PIDController{
    [SerializeField] public float p;
    [SerializeField] public float i;
    [SerializeField] public float d;
    private float oldError;
    private float integralSum;

    public float Update(float dt, float current, float target) {
        float error = target - current;
        float P = p * error;

        float errorChange = (error - oldError) / dt;
        oldError = error;
        float D = d * errorChange;

        integralSum = integralSum + (error * dt);
        float I = i * integralSum;

        return P + I + D;
    }
}
```

```csharp
public PIDController pid;
public float steerAngle, acceleration, velocity;

/////////////////////////

horizontal = horizontalInput * 40;
acceleration = pid.Update(Time.deltaTime, steerAngle, horizontal);
velocity += acceleration * Time.delaTime;
steerAngle += (acceleration / 2 * Time.deltaTime + velocity) * Time.deltaTime;
wheelColliders[0].steerAngle = steerAngle;
wheelColliders[1].steerAngle = steerAngle;
```

I would recomend reading about PID controllers, but here is a quick guide:

- p is how strong you want your system to react
- d is how quickly you want your system to calm down
- i is how quick you want to force the system to reach the target

Comment: I was trying to implement this code and it seemed to be implemented correctly, but i was getting some really weird outputs for the steering angle. What numbers would you recommend using for P, I and D? Seems to just throw some crazy number out with not exact pattern i can see

Comment: @aemeny I have to apologize, my initial answer had disregarded that the wheelcollider steering isn't a physics based system with inertia. You got weird behavior since the PID is trying to compensate for something that didn't exist. I have edited my answer and implemented a simple "wheel steering" simulation that should create a more reasonable behavior for any positive P, I and D values. In my test setup I have used P = 10, D = 3 and I = 1.